# Window.open makes the page into a popup block

Tags: javascript, jquery, popupwindow, window.open

Below is my code for opening the button into a new page, but there are more complexity on the on click function. Here the post process also happens, which makes the window.open in as popup block.

I have tried to remove the post function and tried and the new page works perfectly. could anybody help out in this issue.

```
$('#catalog_demo_button a').click(function(e) {         
        var curEmailId = $('#field-email').val();           
        var validemail = validateEmail(curEmailId);
        if (validemail) 
        {   
        RSUI.util.setCookie("curEmailIdsc", curEmailId);
        $.post($("#targetform").val(), 
        {
            email : $('#field-email').val(),
            demo_lang : $('#selectedLang').val(),
            cis_name : $("#cis_name").val(),
            website : $("#website").val(),
            form_type : "demo",
            demo_type : $("#form_type").val(),
            form_url : $("#form_url").val(),
            cid : $.trim(RSUI.util.getCookie('affiliate'))
        },function(data) 
        {
            if (data != "")
            {
                data = eval("("+data+")");
                if (data[0].cisFlag == "true")                                  
                {                           
                    s.events="event19";
                    s.t();
                    delete s.events;
                    s.sendFormEvent('s', s.pageName, "Demo Email Form");
                    adconionConversionCall();   



                    var demolangid = $("[name=language_code]").val();
                    URL= 'url'+demolangid; 
                        if(demolangid == 'ENG' || demolangid == 'ESC' || demolangid == 'ESP' || demolangid == 'DEU' || demolangid == 'FRA' || demolangid == 'ITA' || demolangid == 'SVE')   
                            $('#demo').overlay().load();
                        else
                            window.open(URL,'_blank')
                            $("#demoform a.close").click();
                    }
                else {
                    s.sendFormEvent('e', s.pageName, "Demo Email Form", "Email Submission Failed");
                }
            }   
        }, "");
    }
        else 
        {
            $("#field-email").val(errorEmailText);
            $('#field-email').css('border', '1px solid red');
            s.sendFormEvent('e', s.pageName, "Demo Email Form", "field-email");
        }
    });
```

Comment: What's causing the block? Your browser or a toolbar?

Comment: The Browser only creates the block. If i click allow the popup, then no problem, but this itself should not happen.

Comment: Ok I will share a bit of valuable knowledge from a previous post here: your popup is blocked by browser if it detects that the `open popup` command is not executed when a user action occurs. You seem to be doing an ajax call after user click. This might be the reason. You can try and see if opening a popup works if you put popup code as first line of `click()` handler without any conditions. I can't think of the solution though!

Comment: thanks for your reply, ya it works on that case if i remove the conditions,. but this ajax call only make some problem, this new window should open only on the success case of the ajax call and posting datas.

Answer (score 1):

Popups are blocked when not invoked by a user action. Your window.open is not in the user action but in the POST success callback.

You should either make the post synchronous and do the window.open from outside the POST success(untested, but sounds logical) or first open the popup and fill it in later.

Comment: Almost want to give a -1 for suggesting a synchronous post back. That is asking for more trouble.

Comment: I concur. Ideally I would avoid the problem as a whole and not depend on a popup window.